# How to align the search bar to the other side in navbar bootstrap 5

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I have a navbar and the navbar has some items which are aligned on the left and a search bar which is aligned on the right side of the navbar. I want to align the items on the right and the search bar on the right but when I add the ms-auto class only the items move to the right and the search bar doesn't move to the left and stays there

How can I basically rotate the navbar so the items stay on the right and the search bar stays on the left?

Here's my code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
   <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarScroll">
         <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto my-2 my-lg-0 navbar-nav-scroll" style="--bs-scroll-height:100px;">
            <li class="nav-item">
               <a href="#" class="nav-link active" aria-current="page">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
               <a href="#" class="nav-link">About us</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
               <a href="#" class="nav-link">Contact us</a>
            </li>
         </ul>
         <form class="d-flex">
            <input type="search" class="form-control me-2" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
         </form>
      </div>
   </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Put `dir="rtl"` on the `html` tag.

Comment: @ServeshChaturvedi I did and changed the me-auto to ms-auto and the items wouldnt stick to the right side like they did to the left, there is some kind of space between the items and the right border

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not getting your query. ms-auto works for me in the ul. Please share an image to illustrate your issue

Comment: i checked the bootstrap documents and found out i have to use the rtl file and it just worked out. thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

I changed an order between form and ul and I added a class d-flex justify-content-between to div collapse

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Zenh87qX5JnK2Jl0vWa8Ck2rdkQ2Bzep5IDxbcnCeuOxjzrPF/et3URy9Bv1WTRi" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Carusel</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-OERcA2EqjJCMA+/3y+gxIOqMEjwtxJY7qPCqsdltbNJuaOe923+mo//f6V8Qbsw3" crossorigin="anonymous" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <div class="container-fluid">
           <div class="collapse navbar-collapse d-flex justify-content-between" id="navbarScroll">
              <form class="d-flex">
                 <input type="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                 <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
              </form>
               <ul class="navbar-nav my-2 my-lg-0 navbar-nav-scroll" style="--bs-scroll-height:100px;">
                 <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link active" aria-current="page">Home</a>
                 </li>
                 <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">About us</a>
                 </li>
                 <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Contact us</a>
                 </li>
              </ul>
           </div>
        </div>
     </nav>
</body>
</html>
```